# Strange behaviour of gsub in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

```
puts 'the\t\'arget'.gsub("'", "\\'")
```

produces following output:

```
the\targetarget
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\\'` in the gsub replacement is actually a back reference, which is replacing a `'` character with everything after the `'` character in the original string, which is *arget*.

This is a quote from the [ruby docs on `String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form \\d, where d is a group number, or \\k, where n is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement the special match variables, such as &$, will not refer to the current match.